# Altium Designer - How to change width and gap of differential pairs without rerouting?

Tags: pcb, altium, differential, layout, designer

As the title already states, is there a way to change the width and espacially the gap of a differential pair after routing?

In Altium Designer you can easily change the width of both of the differential pair tracks, but if you do so the gap of the diff pair changes depending on the change of the width. I'm searching for a way to adjust the width of both tracks and maintain the gap between them.

I searched the Altium documentation and googled a bit but couldn't find any solutions. I'm afraid there is no easy way to do this, but first let's hear your suggested solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to try to find a geometry that meets your needs, but instead of adjusting the width and keeping the gap the same, adjust both of them in a way that keeps the center-to-center distance the same.

Comment: @ThePhoton By changing only the width of both tracks the center-to-center distance keeps the same, but this is not what I want to achive.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If the goal is to adjust the characteristic impedance, then you can likely do it by changing both width and spacing (keeping center-to-center the same) just as well as by changing the width without changing the spacing. And doing so would avoid having to re-route the tracks, which is what you asked for.

Comment: If you are trying to reduce the characteristic impedance and already have the minimum spacing for your technology, then you're stuck --- you'll have to re-route the tracks. ... Or reduce the dielectric thickness to bring the ground plane closer.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to adjust my layer stack after routing all of my differential pairs. Therefore the layout to achive the characteristical impedance slightly changed (gap is the same, width is a bit smaller). If I adjust the width to the appropriate value, than the gap isn't correct anymore. The center-to-center value stays the same, but this isn't decisive for the characteristic impedance.

Comment: There should be a way to not adjust the width by as much, but keep the center-to-center distance the same, and meet your impedance goal. The only problem comes if this reduces the gap to something not manufacturable. If you share the actual geometry, I could demonstrate with real numbers.

Comment: If you're using a full-service fab shop, you could even ask them to calculate the new geometry for you. Adjusting the characteristic impedance without changing center-to-center distance is something they do a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice @ThePhoton. I will try to solve this problem with our fabrication partner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you update the design rules, the **Retrace** feature can somewhat intelligently update the traces.  See:

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/post-route-glossing-and-retracing-ad#!retrace-your-routes

It tends to work better in recent versions of Altium (20, 21), and requires good design-rule discipline.  It can also do some stupid things at times, especially when entering pads or with fly-by connections, so it requires close supervision.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I have searched for. Thank you! Unfortunatly I don't get it to work. As I have read in the documentation the retrace feature will retrace the track with the preferred track witdh/gap specified by the design rules. In my design rules I have specified a width of 0.25 mm for a 50-Ohm track. I select a track on my design (which is affected by that rule) with a width of 0.255 mm and select Route -> Retrace Selected. But it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have tested some other tracks with other rules and specified widths/gaps, but it doesn't work for me. Any ideas why it might fail?